# Can we have an option to hide the excerpt from the full tag wiki entry?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

When the new excerpt system was implemented, I liked that the excerpt was separate from the start of the article - it let me focus on the quick and short for the immediately visible blurb, while allowing more detailed verbiage and formatting in the start of the actual article. It was also useful if the start would trail into a list or summat, as I could opt to trim the excerpt to just the part before a list.

But a recent change has now made the excerpt visible on the wiki entry, which has led to a very ugly duplication of content on a few articles. The boxed border, to me at least, also breaks up the flow from the "start" of the article to the rest.

Could we have an option, while editing the wiki, to hide that excerpt from the full entry's display? I figure that allowing it to stick around or not gives better flexibility than sticking to one option.

Comment: yes this drives me nuts .... I may have an idea here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guess what?

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/status-completed/info