# Should Tag-Wiki bodies repeat the excerpt?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should the tag excerpt be included in the body as well?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78419/should-the-tag-excerpt-be-included-in-the-body-as-well)

On the 'Tagged Questions' pages, the first thing you see is the Wiki text.  The excerpt is not shown.  I've recently run across several where the body is written as a continuation of the excerpt, and so the description seems to start in the middle of a thought.  [`Bootloader`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootloader) is an example, as is [`Embedded`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded).

On the other hand the [`c`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) wiki does essentially repeat the excerpt, and it reads much better when you go to that tag page.

This question: ["Should the tag excerpt be included in the body as well?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78421/132789) advises that the excerpt should not be repeated.  That may be bad advice, since the page which people land on first after clicking a tag does not show the excerpt.

Should there be a policy of repetition, and should I start editing the wikis that don't?

Comment: If you disagree with the answer(s) to an existing question, you should post an answer justifying your opinion to that question. Meta doesn't work any differently in this regard than Stack Overflow. There's no need to post a *new* question.

Comment: Something is better than nothing...